# Multirowed multicolumn

Tags: tables

I need something like that:

```
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{in this place I want multirow text like in fixed width cells without multicolumn}
```

Without use `\makecell` and `\\` in it.

Is it possible?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|} 
  \hline 
  This text block is automaticaly goes down. It makes multirow. 
    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{This text is not :( even if the cell width is fixed. It breaks the table. } 
    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} \\ 
  \hline &&&& \\ 
  \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline
This text block is automaticaly goes down. It makes multirow. & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{This text is not :( even if the cell width is fixed. It breaks the table. } & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} \\hline
&&&& \\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Answer (score 1):

If you set `l` column type, line breaks are not allowed, period.

We must use `p` column type once again, but calculate the width based on how many columns are spanned, like this:

```
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 3cm + 2\tabcolsep\relax}|}%
```

`3cm` is the sum of the columns merged (`1.5cm` + `1.5cm`) and the added `2\tabcolsep` is for recovering the space between the merged cells (there should be 2 `\tabcolsep`s added for each column separator that is spanned).

I've also added the `array` package, which isn't strictly necessary, but I used `>{\raggedright}` from that package to set your `p` columns ragged right, which tends to look better for these very narrow columns.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|} 
  \hline 
  This text block is automatically goes down. It makes \verb+multirow+. 
    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr 3cm + 2\tabcolsep\relax}|}%
      {This text is not :( even if the cell width is fixed. It breaks the table. }
    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} \\ 
  \hline &&&& \\ 
  \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]